# how to add the values from the output of below sql query

Tags: sql-server

I have a below query which execute 20 select statements and output also shows 20 results, i need to sum up all the values and get a single value as output please provide the query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename1 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename2 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename3 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename4 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename5 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename6 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename7 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename8 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename9 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename10 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename11 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename12 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename13 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename14 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename15 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename16 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename17 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename18 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename19 WHERE SERVERID=1;
```

please provide a query to add up all the values which i get from the above output

Comment: select sum(your_alias) from ( your_query) subquery.  add alias to count(*) as your_alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Sum(SumCount) AS TotalCount
From
(
SELECT COUNT(1) AS SumCount FROM Tablename WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Tablename1 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Tablename2 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Tablename3 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Tablename4 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Tablename5 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Tablename6 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Tablename7 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Tablename8 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Tablename9 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Tablename10 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Tablename11 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Tablename12 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Tablename13 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Tablename14 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Tablename15 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Tablename16 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Tablename17 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Tablename18 WHERE SERVERID=1
union
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Tablename19 WHERE SERVERID=1
)
Dt;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can place your series of unions into a CTE and then just take the sum:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM Tablename WHERE SERVERID = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename1 WHERE SERVERID = 1
    UNION ALL
    ...
)
SELECT SUM(total) AS grand_total
FROM cte
```

Another approach would be to take the union off all the tables, and then count the number of records.  But this might use more memory than counting each table separately as the query above does.

Comment: Should probably be `UNION ALL`. I know the OP has just used `UNION` in the question, but it is unlikely that if all 20 tables had 1 record they would expect a result of 1.

Comment: @GarethD Good point.  Lesson learned about blindly copying the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
            SELECT T1+T2+T3+T4+T5+T6+T7+T8+T9+T10+T11+T12+T13+T14+T15+T16+T17+T18+T19+T20 
            AS TotalCount from
            (
            SELECT
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename WHERE SERVERID=1) as T1,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename1 WHERE SERVERID=1) as T2,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename2 WHERE SERVERID=1) as T3,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename3 WHERE SERVERID=1) as T4,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename4 WHERE SERVERID=1) as T5,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename5 WHERE SERVERID=1) as T6,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename6 WHERE SERVERID=1) as T7,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename7 WHERE SERVERID=1) as T8,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename8 WHERE SERVERID=1) as T9,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename9 WHERE SERVERID=1) as T10,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename10 WHERE SERVERID=1) as T11,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename11 WHERE SERVERID=1) as T12,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename12 WHERE SERVERID=1) as T13,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename13 WHERE SERVERID=1) as T14,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename14 WHERE SERVERID=1) as T15,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename15 WHERE SERVERID=1) as T16,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename16 WHERE SERVERID=1) as T17,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename17 WHERE SERVERID=1) as T18,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename18 WHERE SERVERID=1) as T19,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tablename19 WHERE SERVERID=1) as T20
            ) u
```

Comment: Hi If  there are  1000 of tables then you can keep on writing code As T1,T2..........?

Answer (score 0):

By Using dynamic Sql You can find Record Count of all the Tables  Named Like 'Tablename'. Just Go through the below code

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#TableName') IS NOT NULL
Drop table #TableName

IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#TableQuery') IS NOT NULL
Drop table #TableQuery

CREATE TABLE #TableQuery (TableQuery VARCHAR(max))

CREATE TABLE #TableName (
    Id INT IDENTITY
    ,TableName VARCHAR(200)
    )

INSERT INTO #TableName (TableName)
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
AND TABLE_NAME Like '%Tablename%'
ORDER BY 1

DECLARE @MinID INT,@MaxId INT,@Sql nvarchar(max),@TableNAme varchar(100),@Sql2 nvarchar(max)
SELECT @MinID=Min(Id),@MaxId=Max(Id) from #TableName
WHile (@MinID <=@MaxId)
Begin
Select @TableNAme=TableName From #TableName Where Id=@MinID
SET @Sql='
                SELECT COUNT(1) As SUmTotal From '+@TableNAme +' WHERE SERVERID=1 Union all'

SET @MinID=@MinID+1

INSERT INTO #TableQuery
SELECT @Sql
END
SELECT @Sql2=REPLACE(Replace(Query,'&#x0D;',''),',','') FRom
(
SELECT DISTINCT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(TableQuery)) AS VARCHAR(100)) FROM #TableQuery
For XML PATH('')),1,1,'' ) AS Query FROM #TableQuery
)Dt
SELECT @Sql2=SUbSTRING(@Sql2,1,Len(@Sql2)-LEN('Union all'))
SET @Sql2='SELECT  SUM(SUmTotal) AS TotalCount From ('+@Sql2+ ' ) AS Dt'
SELECT @Sql2

Exec(@Sql2)
```